# What are these little insects in that I found in my greenhouse?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found these little (3-4mm) insects in my indoor greenhouse where I propagate Begonia from leaf cuttings.

They are slowly walking around on the soil and don't seem to be particularly interested in the plants. When I disturb them they start running around quite fast.

The (unfortunately low quality) pictures show some individuals that I managed to move into a test tube.

location: Switzerland.

the insects immediately make themselves drop when you try to lift them up with a piece of paper.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Short answer

I think this could possibly be the nymph of some sort of **cockroach**.

#### Long answer

I initially thought these were [aphids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid) of some type due to their pear-like body shapes and the small pair of upright projections coming off their backsides (possibly [cornicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornicle)?).

[image]

However, zooming into some of your more-detailed specimens in the 2nd photo immediately made me questions this:

Your specimen appears to lack a prominent [cauda](http://aphid.aphidnet.org/cauda.php) sticking off the center of their backside; further, they appear to have some sort of [palps](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/fact-files/mouthparts.html) around the mouth and a fairly [hypognathus](http://www.jnkvv.org/PDF/0704202020123064201202.pdf) head -- all of these characteristics are inconsistent with any aphids I know.

Lack of a [furcula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furcula_(springtail)) (among other details) rules out [springtails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail).

Your specimens appear to have [filiform antennae](https://genent.cals.ncsu.edu/bug-bytes/head/antennae/), which doesn't preclude aphids or many other insect orders including beetles, roaches, and orthopterans (e.g., grasshoppers).

Your one specimen appears to have a prominent posterior [femur](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/glossary/terms/femur/) (upper part of leg), suggesting these insects may be good jumpers. However, it could be that the enlarged region is in fact a [coxa](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/glossary/terms/coxa) or that other enlarged femurs are simply less apparent from your photo. Regardless, given the enlarged leg and your observed running behavior, I'd guess these are [cursorial](https://genent.cals.ncsu.edu/bug-bytes/thorax/legs/) legs adapted for -- in fact -- running! [See [here](http://www.entomologa.ru/outline/22.htm) for more on legs].

- Running vs jumping rules out [orthoptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoptera) nymphs of any kind.

Given the head type, body shape, mouth parts, rear projections (likely [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus) not cornicles), and rear leg anatomy, I suppose this is some sort of **cockroach ([Blattodea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blattodea)) nymph**.

Here is an example:

[image]

<sup>[*Ectobius pallidus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectobius_pallidus) - young nymph (<3mm) ; Source: [JungleDragon](https://www.jungledragon.com/image/69169/ectobius_pallidus_-_young_nymph.html)</sup>

Due to the poor quality of the photo, I think I'll stop here. You'll have to explore possible species based on your ability to ascertain in-person detail.

- Alternatively, someone else might know a more specific group/species and/or may propose another order of insect all together. We'll see..

I'll consider updating if you provide additional detail.

---

<sup>Also, I'm going to pitch the informative Insects information page from NC State University: https://content.ces.ncsu.edu/extension-gardener-handbook/4-insects</sup>

Comment: It's just great to read such an analytical answer to my question. Thank you!

Comment: @ert22 thanks! Glad I could help. Would you say your specimens looked anything like the photo I include? (i.e., am I close?? :p -- the photos really make it hard to tell!)